How to know when an anchor tag (<a>) file download has finished?
I have a Blazor-Server application that has file downloads on a page.
When the user downloads a large file (>250MB), it is temporarily created in a physical path in the Server, gets downloaded and then should be deleted from the physical path in the Server.
The issue is I cannot delete the file before the user has finished downloading and therefore I need a way to know when this process is completed.
I am currently using the Microsoft suggested method for downloading large files in Blazor-Server with a few additions like so:
await module.InvokeVoidAsync("triggerFileDownload", fileName, urlFilePath);

And JavaScript like so:
const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
if (typeof anchorElement.download === 'undefined') {
    window.location = url;
}
else {
    anchorElement.href = url;
    if (triggerFileDownload) {
        anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
    }
    anchorElement.target = '_blank';
    document.body.appendChild(anchorElement);
    anchorElement.click();
    document.body.removeChild(anchorElement);
}

url: the physical path of the file temporarily saved in the Server
JavaScript Interop does not wait for the download. As soon as the anchor element is removed from the body, C# takes over and just continues so deleting the file right after is not an option.

deleting the file I'm afraid it's hard to make the application running in the server to delete a file in downloaded to the client. If the download occurred in the server, then the blazor application should require windows permission to delete file as well ..

@Tiny I want to delete the file that is created on the Server. Not the one the user has downloaded. I edited the post to make it more clear. Thank you!

Then what we required is a callback for file downloaded and a method to delete the file with the file path and file name, am I right?

I didn't find any OnDownloadCompleted or similar options in blazor to detect the file has been downloaded. Since you mentioned that the file is created on the Server, is it possible for us to create another background service to delete these files at a specific time every day?

@Tiny Yes of course. A service is an option. I just wanted to try to do it without a service, just deleting each file as soon as it got downloaded but unfortunately it seems there is no way of knowing when a browser download is finished. Thank you anyway!

you should be returning File(...) from the endpoint.  That'll take a stream.  If the File has to be created first, you can write it to a memorystream (it loads entire file into buffer, unlike filestream) and then delete the file.  Pass the memorystream into File(...) to be returned.  File class disposes of all streams after response has been sent.  If you don't need to create an actual file first, you can give File class a byte array.

btw, better to POST to trigger this so you won't mess with the URL bar.  You can also write this file to a folder outside of user-access... a folder only your code has access to.  Then have the endpoint serve the file by passing primary key id, and after ensuring the user is authorized.    (maybe that would help with the need to delete the file?)
